# How to write up a loop when certain value hits condition and stop the loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

Problem Statement:
I want to find the n_components where explained_variance_ratio.sum() hit 1 first. End the loop and append to the list.

[image]

```
X.shape
(200, 6395)
```

Here's my code, needs some advice. The code is not efficient becasue I need to set a constant sadly.

Latest edits:

```
res=[]
for i in range(0,X.shape[1],50):
    svd=TruncatedSVD(i)
    svd.fit(X)
    if svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() > 0.95 and svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() <1:
        res.append([i,svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()])
        break
    else:
        continue
    break


res
[[200, 0.9999999999999998]]
```

Comment: Please copy paste your code instead of posting images of code

Comment: use `break` to stop the loop

Comment: Where does the code "set a constant?"

Comment: @shree.pat18 edited thanks

Comment: use break or make this loop a function and return when the condition is true

Comment: @MichaelRuth if svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() <= constant(0.98) here's the constant.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori I tried the break, did not return as expected. Probably I am doing wrong

Comment: @Goion Please check my break condition not working as expected

Comment: why did you change from if to while. this is confusing. imo you don't need that while loop

Comment: @Goion Please check again looks like its working. One more thing why  the results in list not incremented by 100?

Comment: Can you remove old code. It is confusing :(

Comment: The sum of 200 and 0.999.... is greater than 0.95. Isn't that what you want? remove extra stuff and add expected output.

Comment: @Goion Yea it kinda solved my problem. But I have to set up these 2 conditions >0.95 & <0.1. Anyways thanks for the directions dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work:

```
res=[]
for i in range(0,X.shape[1],50):
    svd=TruncatedSVD(i)
    svd.fit(X)
    if svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() > 0.95 and svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() <1:
        res.append([i,svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()])
    else:
        break
```